# Linux / NVMe, disable interrupt coalescing

Tags: linux, pci-express, pci, nvme

I'm looking at testing an NVMe device with interrupt coalescing enabled, and disabled.

NVMe protocol defined interrupt coalescing parameters that can be passed to the device, and in free BSD the nvme module has these parameters to configure:

```
dev.nvme.0.int_coal_time
    (R/W) Interrupt coalescing timer period in microseconds.  Set to
    0 to disable.

dev.nvme.0.int_coal_threshold
    (R/W) Interrupt coalescing threshold in number of command comple-
    tions.  Set to 0 to disable.
```

With linux, I can't seem to see anything much about interrupt coalescing (interrupt moderation) outside of ethernet adapters, so I'm wondering if I'm looking in entirely the wrong place.